# Remove footer (page number) in documents that are one page long

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

When I create a document that has but one page, I see no reason to have a page number in the footer. I would like to remove this. There is, however, apparently no such equivalent to `thispagestyle{plain}`, which removes the header on the first page. I would have thought `thispagestyle{headings}` would do the trick, but no.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[L]{My name}
    \fancyhead[R]{My affiliation}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{headings} % this removes my header and puts the page number there
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: @azetina I only want to remove the footer, not the header.

Comment: Add `\fancyfoot{}`

Comment: Where? xxxxxxxxx

Comment: See my answer below :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `\fancyfoot{}` removes the footer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[L]{My name}
    \fancyhead[R]{My affiliation}
    \fancyfoot{}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After `\pagestyle{fancy}` it's usually better to say `\fancyhf{}` that clears all the six fields, so that you can decide what to put in each one. If you don't specify `\fancyfoot`, nothing will go in the footer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{My name}
\fancyhead[R]{My affiliation}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to load any package to do this you can just redefine the footers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\@evenfoot{}
\def\@oddfoot{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```