# \@fancyhead undefined in Tex Live 2017

Tags: errors, fancyhdr, texlive-2017

The following code from [Automatically remove ruler when no header is present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165914/2693) compiles fine in Tex Live 2016:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \makeatletter
    \let\org@fancyhead\@fancyhead
    \renewcommand*{\@fancyhead}[5]{\sbox0{#2#3#4}\ifdim\wd0=\z@ \let\headrule\relax \fi \org@fancyhead{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}} % remove ruler if header is empty
    \makeatother

\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

But in Tex Live 2017, it gives the error `LaTeX Error: \@fancyhead undefined`. Why? And how can I fix this?

Comment: This is the danger of depending on internal macros of a package. The `\@fancyhead` macro has been renamed `\f@nch@head` (and a lot of other similar macros have also been renamed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reasons that aren't documented in the change history, lots of internal macros in `fancyhdr` have changed names. This is one of the dangers of depending on code that modifies such internal macros as opposed to modifying user facing macros. In this particular case, `\@fancyhead` is now `\f@nch@head`.  So the following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\let\org@fancyhead\f@nch@head
\renewcommand*{\f@nch@head}[5]{\sbox0{#2#3#4}\ifdim\wd0=\z@ \let\headrule\relax \fi \org@fancyhead{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}} % remove ruler if header is empty
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\begin{document}
\section{My first section}
\lipsum
\newpage
\fancyhead[C]{Header is set}
\section{My next section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```