# Conditionals—do something, if a given command is being used in the document

Tags: macros, conditionals

Is it possible to have a conditional that allow us to do something *if* a given command is being used in the *document*? For example for the `\part` command would be:

```
\@ifcommandisbeingused{\part}{<then>}{<else>}
```

### Clarification

The following would avoid the `\bfseries` for the chapter entry in the TOC, because the `\part` command is being used in the *document*.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter

\@ifcommandisbeingused{\part}
{  
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
}{}

\makeatother    

\begin{document}

\part{Lorem}
\chapter{Ipsum}

\end{document}
```

---

P.S.

I've changed `\@ifcommandIsBeingUsed` to `\@ifcommandisbeingused` 'cause I've remembered that in TeX/LaTeX language is common to use uppercase letters only in "very low level" macros.

Comment: Note that usage of such a command would at least require two compiles since you may want to use `\@ifcommandIsBeingUsed` *before* it is actually used...

Comment: LaTeX is turring-complete, so yes. I recently used the `ifthen` package in an answer here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165873/automatically-remove-page-number-in-one-page-documents/165882#165882

Comment: To clarify, you wish this command to discern whether a macro has actually been invoked, and not just if it has been defined.  Is that correct?

Comment: Also, when you say "is being used", do you mean "will be used at some point" or "has been used to this point" in the document?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I hope my update will answer your questions.

Answer (score 4):

This solution creates a file `\jobname.use` which tracks, which commands have been used. You add a command to the list by doing `\ifused\<command>{<hook>}`. In the example I used `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` to remove `\bfseries` from `\l@chapter`. Doing `\ifused` twice for the same command will produce errors.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\file_if_exist:nT { \c_job_name_tl . use }
 { \file_input:n { \c_job_name_tl . use } }

\iow_new:N \l_cloud_used_stream
\iow_open:Nn \l_cloud_used_stream { \c_job_name_tl . use  }
\AtEndDocument { \iow_close:N \l_cloud_used_stream }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cloud_is_used:N #1
 {
  \iow_now:Nx \l_cloud_used_stream
   { \exp_not:N \bool_set_true:c { l _ cloud _ if \cs_to_str:N #1 _ bool } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ifused}{mm}
 {
  \preto #1 { \cloud_is_used:N #1 }
  \iow_now:Nx \l_cloud_used_stream
   { \exp_not:N \bool_new:c { l _ cloud _ if \cs_to_str:N #1 _ bool } }
  \bool_if:cT { l _ cloud _ if \cs_to_str:N #1 _ bool } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\ifused\part{\patchcmd\l@chapter{\bfseries}{}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Before first part}
\part{First part}
\chapter{After first part}
\part{Second part}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: `\preto` =? `\tl_put_left:Nn`?

Comment: @Manuel Indeed that works, but it shadows the initial intention. Unfortunately there is no `\cs_put_left:Nn`.

Comment: `\cs_put_left:Nn` would be more like `\pretocmd`. I think `\tl_put_left:Nn` is fine here, but it's true what you say :)

Comment: Note that `\c_job_name_tl` has been replaced by `\c_sys_jobname_str` in the September 2015 release of `expl3`.